# How to create and use an R function in SAS 9.4?

Tags: r, sas, sas-macro

I have defined some R functions in R studio which has some complicated scripts and a lot of readlines. I can run them successfully in R studio. Is there any way, like macros to transfer these user-defined functions to SAS 9.4 to use? I am not pretty familiar with SAS programming so it is better just copy the R functions into SAS and use it directly. I am trying to figure out how to do the transformation. Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.  Having said all that, the answer is that you can always call R.exe or any interpreter from an app like SAS or a language that supports it BUT no, there's no tool that automatically converts all of your code. Such a library would be unreasonably difficult to maintain especially considering libraries w/in languages.

Comment: You can run R code within SAS. See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/64248/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_sect004.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't natively run R code in SAS, and you probably wouldn't want to.  R and SAS are entirely different concepts, SAS being closer to a database language while R is a matrix language.  Efficient R approaches are terrible in SAS, and vice versa.  (Try a simple loop in R and you'll find SAS is orders of magnitude faster; but try matrix algebra in R instead).

You can *call* R in SAS, though.  You need to be in PROC IML, SAS's matrix language (which may be a separate license from your SAS); once there, you use [submit / R](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/67502/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_toc.htm) to submit the code to R. You need the RLANG system option to be set, and you may need some additional details set up on your SAS box to make sure it can see your R installation, and you need R 3.0+.  You also need to be running SAS 9.22 or newer.

If you don't have R available through IML, you can use `x` or `call system`, if those are enabled and you have access to R through the command line.  Alternately, you can run R by hand separately from SAS.  Either way you would use a CSV or similar file format to transfer data back and forth.

Finally, I recommend seeing if there's a better approach in SAS for the same problem you solved in R.  There usually is, and it's often quite fast.